# Turn off line wrap in Gedit

Tags: gnome, gedit

I've been using kwrite for a long time and love the way I can turn on/off line wrapping easily. Now I'm running Ubuntu with GNOME, trying to avoid any KDE at all on this particular machine. Gedit seems to always wrap lines with no way to turn it off. Am I missing some well-hidden option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > View Tab > Text Wrapping options right there, front and center. Not "well hidden" by any means.

Comment: That seems a bit deep for turning on and off routinely.  Kwrite has it immediately available in the menu bar's View.

Comment: It's be nice if there were a hotkey for that.

Comment: Get the source code and make the change yourself. Great opportunity to learn. :)

Comment: @DarenW, see  WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### UPDATE:

In 3.14.3 (and perhaps earlier) and in newer versions of gedit, there is a "Text wrapping" checkbox when you click on the "Line/Column" indicator on the status bar, in bottom right corner of the window.

---

#### IN VERY OLD VERSIONS:

As of gedit 10.4, there is no preferences dialog anymore. Some of the options are now in the status bar, but not word-wrapping.

You can turn word wrapping off by tweaking the GSettings settings. To do so, run the following command in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode none
```

Besides `none`, you can also turn it back on with either `word`, `char`, or `word-char` word wrapping.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for enabling and disabling wrapping?

Comment: @htellez my current gedit (3.16.2) has a "Text wrapping" option if you click on the right part of your status bar (where Ln, Col. numbers are)

Comment: Thanks @istepaniuk. I don't see such an option and I'm using 3.10.4. Could you share a screenshot? I would prefer a 'no mouse' way to do it, is always faster using keyboard shortcuts than using the mouse and I have been wrapping/unwrapping a lot lately.

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed your gedit version was higher than mine until now. Anyway, do you know if there is a way to make a keyboard shortcut MACRO  with it?

Comment: in 3.14.3 there also is a "warp" checkbook if you click the "Ln .., Cl .." bar at the bottom, thank you @istepaniuk

Answer (score 0):

### When running as root there is no Preferences menu

By default when you run `gedit` as `root` there is no top level menu. The only alternative (in my version 3.18.3) is to click on the last drop down menu on the lower right corner:

[image: gedit text wrap.png]

Notice I have "unchecked" text wrap option to make `/var/log/syslog` file more readable for debugging output.

Comment: This is the answer the OP is looking for, except for the unncessary comments about running as root.