# Config file for gedit to disable line wrap?

Tags: gnome, gedit

Is there a non-interactive way to disable line wrapping in gedit?  i.e., a config file?  I am teaching a class and would like to change the settings for the whole class globally.

(follow-up to [how to turn off line wrap in gedit?](https://superuser.com/questions/253771/how-to-turn-off-line-wrap-in-gedit))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older gEdit used config files (`%gconf.xml`) in the hidden dirs under your `~home` . The new gEdit (v. 3.**) uses `dconf/gsettings` backend and as such it no longer uses config files to load the editor prefs. You can either use `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` (CLI) to change gEdit preferences.
In your case, to disable line-wrap either open a terminal and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode none
```

or fire-up `dconf-editor` and navigate to *org > gnome > gedit > preferences > editor* and in the right pane you will see the key `wrap-mode` (should be the last one). Click'n'hold on its value to change it to 'none' (or GTK_WRAP_NONE on some systems).